# nuget throws error when trying to retrieve package

Tags: c#, nuget

I have project which has the following .nuspec file:

```
<package >
<metadata>
  <id>Dependencies</id>
  <version>1.0.0.0</version>
  <title>Dependencies</title>
  <authors>Author</authors>
  <owners>AnAuthor</owners>
  <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
  <description>NuGet package that is used for dependencies resolution.
  </description>
  <releaseNotes></releaseNotes>
  <copyright>Copyright 2017</copyright>
  <tags>Nuget</tags>
<dependencies>
    <group targetFramework="net40">
      <dependency id="NUnit" version="[2.6.3,)" />
      <dependency id="Internal.Package" version="[2017.2.100.0,)" />
    </group>
</dependencies>
```

Now, when I trying to pack the package:

```
NuGet.exe pack Dependencies.nuspec -Verbosity normal
NuGet.exe install Dependencies -Prerelease -ExcludeVersion -OutputDirectory 
..\..\packages -NoCache -Verbosity normal
```

I get the following error:

```
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Internal.Package (>= 2017.2.100.0)'.
'1.0.0.beta.1' is not a valid version string
```

After checking the package, indeed there is package published with such version. But how come this version became invalid? Can't I insert any character in version format (major.minor.build.rev)? Maybe this is configurable in nuget manager?

Comment: I believe everything before a `-` has to be numeric.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, you're right. Accidentally `beta.1` instead of `beta-1` was used and, indeed, `1.0.0.beta.1` is not a valid version. Probably having bad day. Thanks.

Comment: It shouldn't be beta-1, it should be 1.0.0-beta01 or something like that - the beta being after -.